# How to find NFC TAG detect time and read time?

Tags: android, performance, nfc, performance-testing

I am developing an android application that deals with NFC. I know how to read and write on NFC tag. 
But what i really want to find out is the time taken by the android OS to detect an NFC tag and also the time taken by OS to read the contents.

Right now , i am dealing with `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` , `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`, `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` but it does not solve the problem.

Is there any listener or any intent that i can use to detect the nfc discovery time and read time.?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the same thing and this might help. Feel free to let me know if it makes sense: one way you could do this is to capture a Logcat Log.i(TAG, "...") upon invocation of your onNewIntent(Intent intent) method. This requires you to first launch your application and then try to tap the device on a tag. Since tapping involves physical motion, I did create a robotic system using a servo which brings the tag to the field and measures the movement of tag in time domain when entering the RD field. Remember that your servo system and the device under test must be time synchronized. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Yes you method is correct. we can take an external system to measure the time for placement of tag. But as i was not getting the precise time... it was better to drop the project.